# Agregarle css a un formulario de login

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Soy nuevo en el trabajo, y mi primer tarea es de crear y maquetar algunos formularios de una app que se está desarrollando en la empresa. Sé como estructurarlo con html, pero no sé cómo darle estilo con css. Por ejemplo, así debería quedar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así fue como yo lo hice:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, ¿qué tipo de estilo css debería agregarle al formulario, para que me quede como la imagen de arriba?

Comment: ya linkeaste tu archivo css al html para que tome los estilos?

Comment: [es.so] te da las herramientas necesarias para agregar tu código _como texto, con formato_. En tu caso, incluso puedes agregar un [repro] en la pregunta colocándolo como _snippet_ (con el botón que indica `<>`). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta no queda clara, pero si te refieres al estilo de los colores, te recomiendo utilizar la propiedad `background-image: linear-gradient();`

Te dejo un ejemplo de como aplicarlo a un botón y a un texto.

```css
#btnx{
  width:200px; 
  height:40px; 
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:700;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #93ecee; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #93ecee, #38dfe0, #26da3e, #108c2b);
}

#txtx{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( #93ecee, #38dfe0, #26da3e);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >


<button  class="btn btn-light" id="btnx" type="submit" style=" ">Ingresar</button>

<h1 id="txtx">StackOverflow</h1>
```